# Running parallel processes in Android app

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing

I'm new to Android app programming.

I'm making a native Android app in Java. Inside an Activity, I have some ArrayLists and 3 different functions receiving 2 ArrayLists as parameters and returning an ArrayList based on the content of the 2 parameters. Each function makes different operations and receives different lists as input. Since these 3 functions are independent of each other and since if the 2 ArrayLists are big the execution of these functions can take a while, I would like to execute them in parallel so I don't wait for the first function to complete in order to launch the second function, etc.

Which is the best way to run these functions in parallel and receive their result back in my ViewModel in order to show it in the Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can execute the three functions in parallel using threads or the Executor framework.  Here is an example of ExecutorService

```
 // Create an ExecutorService with a fixed number of threads
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

       // Create the tasks
        Callable<List<Integer>> task1 = () -> function1();
        Callable<List<Integer>> task2 = () -> function2();
        Callable<List<Integer>> task3 = () -> function3();

        // Submit the tasks to the executor
        Future<List<Integer>> result1 = executorService.submit(task1);
        Future<List<Integer>> result2 = executorService.submit(task2);
        Future<List<Integer>> result3 = executorService.submit(task3);


           // Retrieve the results asynchronously
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                List<Integer> resultList1 = result1.get();
                // Process the result of function1
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                List<Integer> resultList2 = result2.get();
                // Process the result of function2
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                List<Integer> resultList3 = result3.get();
                // Process the result of function3
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // Shutdown the executor when you're done
        executorService.shutdown();
}
```